# unable to read indexDB in PWA Android device

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

i can't read anything from index DB only an android device (tablet, smartphone).

do you know what it happens ?

unable to read fcmRecord, it's always empty. I tried
-index of fcmRecord
-Object.keys(fcmRecord).length

and it failed only on android ...

```
my code:

var request = indexedDB.open("my_database", 1);

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;

    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("fcm_token")) {
        var fcmTokenStore = db.createObjectStore("fcm_token", {
            keyPath: "id",
            autoIncrement: true,
        });
    }
};

request.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error(
        "Erreur lors de l'ouverture de la base de données:",
        event.target.errorCode
    );
};

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    


    var transaction = db.transaction(["fcm_token"], "readonly");
   

    var fcmTokenStore = transaction.objectStore("fcm_token");
  

    // Obtenir un enregistrement avec la clé "fcm"
    var getRequest = fcmTokenStore.get(1); 

    getRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
        var fcmRecord = event.target.result;
       
        if (fcmRecord) {
            self.token_firebase = fcmRecord.fcm;
            
        } else {
            
        }
    };

    getRequest.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error(
            "Erreur lors de la récupération de l'enregistrement:",
            event.target.error
        );
    };
};
```

After debugging and android, I think i have no record in INDEXDB on android device instead of IOS.

```
const countRequest = fcmTokenStore.count();
    countRequest.onsuccess = () => {
    self.test_6 = countRequest.result
    };
```

Return 0.